# Is there a simpler way of writing this code than the two ways I have tried?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A word game awards points for the letters used in a word. The lower the frequency of the letter in the English language, the higher the score for the letter. Write a program that asks the user to input a word. The program should then output the score for the word according to the following rules:

[image]

I have tied written two pieces of code for this task I want to know if there are any other more logic and simple ways of doing this.

**First Try:**

```
#Letter Game Challenge
letters = ("e","a","r","i","o","t","n","s","l","c","u","d","p","m","h"
           ,"g","b","f","y","w","k","v","x","z","j","q")

points = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
          ,24,25,26)

def main():
    global word_input
    print ("Input a word to see the score")
    word_input = input()
    if any(letter in word_input for letter in letters):
        l1()
    else:
        print ("Enter a word with letters in!")
        main()

def l1():
    global score
    global lcheck
    lcheck = word_input
    score = 0

    while word_input != "":
         if lcheck == "":
             break


         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "e"):
            num = lcheck.count("e")
            score = score + 1*num
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("e", "")

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "a"):
            num = lcheck.count("a")
            score = score + 2*num
            lcheck = lcheck.replace ("a", "") 

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "r"):
            num = lcheck.count("r")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("r", "")
            score = score + 3*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "i"):
            num = lcheck.count("i")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("i", "")
            score = score + 4*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "o"):
            num = lcheck.count("o")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("o", "")
            score = score + 5*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "t"):
            num = lcheck.count("t")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("t", "")
            score = score + 6*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "n"):
            num = lcheck.count("n")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("n", "")
            score = score + 7*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "s"):
            num = lcheck.count("s")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("s", "")
            score = score + 8*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "l"):
            num = lcheck.count("l")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("l", "")
            score = score + 9*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "c"):
            num = lcheck.count("c")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("c", "")
            score = score + 10*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "u"):
            num = lcheck.count("u")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("u", "")
            score = score + 11*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "d"):
            num = lcheck.count("d")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("d", "")
            score = score + 12*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "p"):
            num = lcheck.count("p")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("p", "")
            score = score + 13*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "m"):
            num = lcheck.count("m")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("m", "")
            score = score + 14*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "h"):
            num = lcheck.count("h")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("h", "")
            score = score + 15*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "g"):
            num = lcheck.count("g")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("g", "")
            score = score + 16*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "b"):
            num = lcheck.count("b")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("b", "")
            score = score + 17*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "f"):
            num = lcheck.count("f")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("f", "")
            score = score + 18*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "y"):
            num = lcheck.count("y")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("y", "")
            score = score + 19*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "w"):
            num = lcheck.count("w")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("w", "")
            score = score + 20*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "k"):
            num = lcheck.count("k")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("k", "")
            score = score + 21*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "v"):
            num = lcheck.count("v")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("v", "")
            score = score + 22*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "x"):
            num = lcheck.count("x")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("x", "")
            score = score + 23*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "z"):
            num = lcheck.count("z")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("z", "")
            score = score + 24*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "j"):
            num = lcheck.count("j")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("j", "")
            score = score + 25*num

         if any(letter in lcheck for letter in "q"):
            num = lcheck.count("q")
            lcheck = lcheck.replace("q", "")
            score = score + 26*num


    print ("The score for that word is ",score)
    print ()
    check()

def check():
    print ("Do you want to go again?")
    again = input().lower
    if again == "y" or again == "yes":
        print()
        main()
    if again == "no" or again == "n":
        print ()
        print ("Bye!")
    else:
        print ()
        print ("Enter a valid input!")
        print ()
        check()


main()
```

**Second Try:**

```
#Letter game challenge
letters = ("e","a","r","i","o","t","n","s","l","c","u","d","p","m","h",
           "g","b","f","y","w","k","v","x","y","z")
gained_point = 0
def main():
    global word_input
    print ("Input a word to see the score")
    word_input = str(input())
    l1(gained_point)

def l1(gained_point):
    score = 0
    linword = len([ltr for ltr in word_input if ltr.isalpha()])
    linword = linword - 1

    while linword > -1:

        if linword < 0:
            break

        position = letters.index(word_input[linword])
        linword = linword - 1
        gained_point = gained_point + position
        gained_point = gained_point + 1


    print ("The score for that word is",gained_point)


main()
```

Comment: This would be better on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

```
letters = ("e","a","r","i","o","t","n","s","l","c","u","d","p","m","h" ,"g","b","f","y","w","k","v","x","z","j","q")
points = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 ,24,25,26)
word = 'nThsnth'

letter_points = dict(zip(letters, points))
total = sum(letter_points.get(c, 0) for c in word.lower())
```